# Can I use generics in Dart like this?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to parse http response to Dart object，so I defined a abstract class

## BaseBean：

```js
abstract class BaseBean{

  BaseBean.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();

}
```

And I used it in a function：

```js
Future<ResultData<T>> netFetch<T extends BaseBean>(){
  ......
  return new ResultData(T.fromJson(), result, code);
}
```

but `T.fromJson()` has an error:

> The method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the class 'Type'

So,can I use generics in Dart like this?Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: @RémiRousselet same error here!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, it is possible, but only with a workaround:

```dart
T unmarshal<T>(Map map, {Type type}) {
  if (type == null) {
    type = T;    
  }

  switch (type) {
    case Order:
      return Order.fromJson(map) as T;
    case OrderItem:
      return OrderItem.fromJson(map) as T;
    case Product:
      return Product.fromJson(map) as T;
    default:
      throw StateError('Unable to unmarshal value of type \'$type\'');
  }
}
```

```dart
var order = unmarshal<Order>(data);
//
var product = unmarshal(data, type: Product) as Product;
//
var type = <String, Type>{};
types['OrderItem'] = OrderItem;
// ...
var type = types['OrderItem'];
var orderItem = unmarshal(data, type: type);
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I used the same approach and I came to this solution.

I created a `Map<Type, BaseBean Function(dynamic)> decoders`.
It looks like

```
final decoders = {
    MyClass: (data) => MyClass.fromJson(data),
};
```

and I get the function in this way

```
final MyClass myData = decoders[T]!(data);
```

You can also create a typedef for the `BaseBean Function(dynamic)` like this

```
typedef Decoder = BaseBean Function(dynamic);
```

So the `Map<Type, BaseBean Function(dynamic)>` will became `Map<Type, Decoder>`.